# Another person is letting me use their bank account to make purchases, what are my risks?

Tags: fraud, paypal, sugar-daddy

I met someone online. They posed as a sugar momma. They NEVER asked for any account or personal info of any kind, and they never received any of my personal information.

They gave me, I have texts and screenshots, permission for each of the three purchases that I have made. Again, using none of my information and using paypal with any changing of funds.

Am I at risk for any laws, fraud etc.?

I would like to reiterate, this person has NONE of my information. They give me permission each time to use their account to send money.

Comment: How did you make purchases? They gave you paypal login info or something?

Comment: Yes, you're at risk. Chances are it wasn't actually their account, but one they compromised via phishing (probably from other victims). You may also see legal exposure for money laundering. Stop doing this.

Comment: @ceejayoz Please [do not answer questions in the comments](https://money.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2298/10997).

Comment: Were you allowed to purchase anything you wanted or were you asked to purchase items from a specific website or seller?

Answer (score 3):

There are a few possibilities here, none of them are good for you.

The most likely is that you're being used as a [money mule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Money_mule) to launder or steal money. You're being enticed by making purchases for yourself from someone else's account. The next step will be for you to buy something and ship it to someone else. This works because the criminals need a "clean" person to access accounts and make purchases. When the fraud is detected it comes back to you and not the criminals coaching you. The sugar momma might not have your info, but the shops and banks will have your info.

The other possibility is that this is part of the control aspect of a sugar momma/sugar daddy arrangement. You're being asked to do jobs for the sugar momma. Eventually she'll ask you to do more like open up your own bank accounts or perform other criminal acts.